# What type of grammar is used to parse PostgreSQL?

Tags: parsing, postgresql, grammar

What type of grammar is used to parse PostgreSQL? Is it LR, LALR, LL, or something else?

Comment: It is likely to be based on an LALR(1) grammar; that's what Yacc/Bison handles normally.  There are likely to be some complications in that; sometimes the SQL grammar gets tricky to handle with LALR(1).

Comment: Source code for parser is here (for latest version) http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=tree;f=src/backend/parser;h=904b1b0bb8bddc95b422b27a3d44fd826dedf736;hb=REL9_1_STABLE

It contain standard LEX and YACC definitions ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [PostgreSQL parser](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/parser-stage.html) is based on [yacc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yacc) and lex. The parsers generated by yacc are LALR(1). You can read postgres' grammar [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/parser/gram.y).

Comment: This was until [8.X version](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/parser-stage.html). In 9+ versions PosgreSQL [is using Bison](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/parser-stage.html), that is full-yacc compatible parser generator.